# Why is Ampère's law violated if there are no fringe fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

What's wrong with the following diagram?

[image]

<sup>Image source: Page 183, [NCERT Physics Textbook for Class XII Part I](http://ncert.nic.in/textbook/textbook.htm?leph1=5-8)</sup>

The reason stated in my textbook is as follows:

> Magnetic field lines between two pole pieces cannot be precisely straight at the ends. Some fringing of lines is inevitable. Otherwise, Ampere’s law is violated. This is also true for electric field lines.

I don't understand how is Ampere's law violated when fringe fields are absent.
Can anyone please explain how Ampere's law is violated?

Comment: Related: [What is the reason for the edge effect in capacitors?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/389766/238167) (Note that the linked question deals with the electric field between the plates of a capacitor whereas this one deals with the magnetic field between the poles of a magnet)

Answer (score 44):

Consider the two paths $ABCDA$ and $EFGHE$.

[image]

Path $AB$ contributes a positive value to the $\vec B\cdot d\vec l$ integral but the other parts of the loop contribute nothing, so overall there is a finite value for the $\vec B\cdot d\vec l$ integral but no enclosed current which violates Ampere's law.

Again path $EF$ contributes a positive value to the $\vec B\cdot d\vec l$ integral but now all the other parts of the loop contribute a negative value to the $\vec B\cdot d\vec l$ integral with the result that the total integral is zero as is the enclosed current.

Comment: Very interesting argument.  ... just wonderin' if you'd have a textbook (or other) reference to this.

Comment: @Zero This really is the qualitative argument in total (a quantitative treatment would be need to get the shape of the lines). I've seen it in several text books, but I don't have mine in front of me today.

Comment: @dmckee Think about me please.  I realize the quantitative aspect would be overly complicated but I've never seen this argument before so I wouldn't mind something beyond PSE I could reference later.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I have not seen a quantitative treatment. Perhaps it would be easier to do the computation for the fringe electric field and hence the line integral for a parallel plate arrangement?

Comment: I think a quantitative approach would completely miss the physics at play here. The whole point is that Ampère's Law requires that the line integral around any loop that passes through this field must be zero due to the lack of current anywhere. The example above shows that, without fringing, any loop that passes outside of the poles would have a net value if there are no field lines there, hence the need for fringing.

Comment: Are the field lines still convex in an absolute vacuum?

Comment: @Willtech Why would you expect them to be different?

Comment: I was supposing that magnetic flux flowing in a non-stationary conductive medium (i.e. air) would create circular currents with their own magnetic field diverting the flux from a strictly direct flow.

Comment: It seems like an incredibly simple and accurate answer, yet I am unable to fully understand it. I'll think more about it.

Comment: @lobotomized_sheep_99 It's a proof by contradiction. Assume $\oint\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l}=0$. If there are no fringe fields, then a closed loop which extends outside the region of the uniform field will give  $\oint\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l}\ne 0$. But that's a contradiction. Therefore, we must have fringe fields.